# log4j2 configuration logging to file but not to console

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

My `log4j2` version is `2.8`

I have the following `log4j2.xml` in `src/main/resources`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Configuration status="WARN" monitorInterval="120">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH.mm.ss} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
        </Console>
        <RollingRandomAccessFile name="RollingRandomAccessFile" fileName="${env:CATALINA_HOME:-.}/logs/applicationlogs.log"
                                 filePattern="${env:CATALINA_HOME:-.}/logs/$${date:yyyy-MM}/applicationlogs-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log.gz">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH.mm.ss} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy />
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="50 MB"/>
            </Policies>
        </RollingRandomAccessFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <AsyncLogger name="com.mypackage" level="trace" includeLocation="true" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="RollingRandomAccessFile"/>
        </AsyncLogger>
        <AsyncLogger name="org.springframework.jdbc" level="debug" includeLocation="true" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="RollingRandomAccessFile"/>
        </AsyncLogger>
        <Root level="info" includeLocation="true">
            <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="RollingRandomAccessFile"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

This logs correctly to the file, but nothing appears on Console.

What's wrong here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per answer above, I did this:

```
<AsyncLogger name="com.mypackage" level="trace" includeLocation="true" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="RollingRandomAccessFile"/>
        </AsyncLogger>
        <AsyncLogger name="org.springframework.jdbc" level="debug" includeLocation="true" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="RollingRandomAccessFile"/>
        </AsyncLogger>
        <AsyncLogger name="com.mypackage" level="info" includeLocation="true" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT"/>
        </AsyncLogger>
        <AsyncLogger name="org.springframework.jdbc" level="info" includeLocation="true" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT"/>
        </AsyncLogger>
```

But now, the logs were coming only to console. Log file remained empty.

So, my final solution was:

```
           <AsyncLogger name="com.mypackage" level="trace" includeLocation="true" additivity="false">
                <AppenderRef ref="RollingRandomAccessFile"/>
            </AsyncLogger>
            <AsyncLogger name="org.springframework.jdbc" level="debug" includeLocation="true" additivity="false">
                <AppenderRef ref="RollingRandomAccessFile"/>
            </AsyncLogger>
            <AsyncLogger name="com.mypackage" level="info" includeLocation="true" additivity="false">
                <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT"/>
                <AppenderRef ref="RollingRandomAccessFile"/>
            </AsyncLogger>
            <AsyncLogger name="org.springframework.jdbc" level="info" includeLocation="true" additivity="false">
                <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT"/>
                <AppenderRef ref="RollingRandomAccessFile"/>
            </AsyncLogger>
```

This worked as expected.

Answer (score 2):

It is because of [additivity attribute](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#Additivity)

> Once an event reaches a logger with its additivity set to false the
>   event will not be passed to any of its parent loggers, regardless of
>   their additivity setting.

So log event just not passed to the root level.
To log to console add

```
<AsyncLogger name="com.mypackage" level="info" includeLocation="true" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT"/>
        </AsyncLogger>
```

Comment: But in that case all trace and debug level logs will be printed on Console as well. I do not want that. All debut and trace should go only to files but as "Root" suggests all info level logs should go to both file as well as console.